# Why is the click on my <li> element not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a simple way to click on an `li` element? I tried some JavaScript methods, but they are not working. I am new to JavaScript, so please do not judge me.

**My HTML code:**

```
<li id="n2" class="Build">
    <a class="inactive" href="newbuild.php" accesskey="2"></a>
</li>
```

**The entire HTML code:**

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li id="n1" class="Ressources">
        <a class="active" href="Ressources.php" accesskey="1"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="n2" class="Build">
        <a class="inactive" href="newbuild.php" accesskey="2"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="n3" class="map">
        <a href="map.php" accesskey="3"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="n4" class="statistics">
        <a href="stat.php" accesskey="4"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="n5" class="reports">
        <a href="reports.php" accesskey="5"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The JavaScript code I tried:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('#n2 li.Build').click(); // Not working

document.querySelector('.Build').click(); //Not Working
```

So how can I click on this `li` (with CSS-Class Build) element? Thank you.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when you click on a List Item?

Comment: Why would you programmatically emulate a click by the user? Because this is what your code does.

Comment: @laruiss i am building a chrome extension and i want to click on this li automaticly if my condition is respected.

Comment: @Thomas i except to be redirected on the link newbuild.php

Comment: So you want to click on the `a` inside, not the `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a click on the `a` element inside the `li`, not the `li` itself:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#n2 li.Build a')[0].click(); // This is bad, btw

// This is also bad, performance-wise: engines read from right to left,
// so the most right-hand part of the selector (key selector)
// should be more precise
document.querySelector('.Build a').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first assign the `click` event listener using `addEventListener` then you can do `document.querySelector('.Build').click();` to trigger the click event in the `.Build` element.

```js
document.querySelector('.Build').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});

document.querySelector('.Build').click();
```

```html
<ul id="navigation">
  <li id="n1" class="Ressources">
    <a class="active" href="Ressources.php" accesskey="1"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="n2" class="Build">
    <a class="inactive" href="newbuild.php" accesskey="2"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="n3" class="map">
    <a href="map.php" accesskey="3"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="n4" class="statistics">
    <a href="stat.php" accesskey="4"></a>
  </li>
  <li id="n5" class="reports">
    <a href="reports.php" accesskey="5"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add a JSfiddle or a working example in your question